# Scrolling material design dialog box in CSS

Tags: css, modal-dialog, material-design

I'm trying to implement the following Material Design dialog box in CSS. This is directly from the [Material Design Specifications](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-content):

[image]

The dialog should expand responsively to fit the screen, but **not overflow** the screen (it should scroll instead).

---

### I'm having trouble finding a decent responsive CSS solution for it

Here is what I've tried (click to expand):

[image]

This dialog expands to fit different screen sizes correctly without overflowing, and also provides a scrollbar when the `content` overflows the `dialog frame`.

**BUT**, the topbar and bottombar will not stick to the top and bottom of the dialog frame (they scroll instead).

Since the `content` of the dialog is indeterminate, I cannot just use fixed headers and footers because the dialog itself may expand or shrink depending on the content.

### Is there a way to create this responsive dialog in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your topbar and bottombar on top of the content, you should put them above/below your content like so:

```
Dialog topbar
/* remove styles */

Dialog bottombar
/* remove styles */

Dialog content
max-height: 50%
overflow: auto

Dialog frame
position: absolute
top: 20%
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  That doesn't seem to work since the `max-height: 50%` doesn't actually work inside an absolute frame.  See this jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/vto0k91m/2/

Comment: oh yes you're right. I think you need some default height for your frame.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes it non responsive so I think I'll need a different solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I can only figure it out with javascript, by setting the content max-height manually:

`$('.content').css('max-height', $('.modal-background').height() *.6 - 90);`

I'm curious if anyone can figure it out without javascript though.